# No web browsers open on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer-8

I'm having a weird problem here. I upgraded a Windows XP computer from IE6 to IE8 yesterday and everything seemed to work normally until today. Now I can't open any browser on this computer. The computer had Google Chrome installed and it suddenly disappeared, I installed it again and now it dowsn't open either. I also installed Firefox and the same thing happened. The computer had no anti virus, I installed Ad-Aware, run a full scan and it detected some malware, but browsers are still not working

Any ideas?

Comment: Check your process list for anything suss, and install some real AV. Because it really does sound malicious code to me...

Comment: Have you tried System Restore ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the computer is infected with some type of malware, that is running a constant "kill xxx" command, causing certain apps to not be able to run. If anti-virus software is unable to clean it, I'd say just wipe and re-install the OS, this should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the problem by restoring the PC to a previous state before installing IE8 and installed a decent antivirus, it seems to be working fine now :)